# How to get contacts from Directory folder using ews-javascript-api?

Tags: node.js, exchangewebservices, ews-javascript-api

[image]

Hi everyone,

I can get all contacts from Your Contacts folder successfully.

How can I get all contacts in that Directory folder from EWS?

I tried this code but it throws error:

> Exception: The distinguished folder name is unrecognized.

```
ews.EwsLogging.DebugLogEnabled = false;
let exch = new ews.ExchangeService(ews.ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);

exch.Credentials = new ews.ExchangeCredentials("username", "password");

exch.Url = new ews.Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/Ews/Exchange.asmx");

exch.FindItems(
    [
        new ews.FolderId(ews.WellKnownFolderName.Directory) // Changed .Contacts to .Directory
    ],
    null,
    null,
    new ews.ItemView(10),
    null,
    ews.ServiceErrorHandling.ReturnErrors
).then(function (resp) {
    resp.Responses[0].Results.Items.forEach(function (item) {
        console.log(item.EmailAddresses.Entries.Values);
    });
}, function (ei) {
    console.log(ei.stack, ei.stack.split("\n"));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `ResolveName` method on `ExchangeService` instance rather than using a folder type. the Directory information is coming from Global Address List in Exchange Populated from Active Directory

reference - 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.resolvename(v=exchg.80).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj190895(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: Thank you for this information. I checked the document and I see that there is a  parameter "nameToResolve: string". => Finds contacts in the Global Address List and/or in specific contact folders that have names that match *the one passed as a parameter*. But I need to get all contacts in Directory folder, no need to match anything.

Comment: you may want to use FindPeople operation which is not yet available in EWS managed api and in ews-javascript-api
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj191039(v=exchg.150).aspx